# php-loep / oauth2-server Fatal error

Tags: php, oauth

Can some one point me in the right direction here, I keep getting the error:
Fatal error: Class 'src\League\OAuth2\Server\Util\Request' not found in F:\Work\xampp\htdocs\oauth\test.php on line 4

after executing the test code below in my test.php from from php-loep / oauth2-server. The Class is there at the right spot. How do I implement this oauth2 server please.

```
<?php
// Initiate the Request handler
$request = new src\League\OAuth2\Server\Util\Request();

// Initiate a new database connection
$db = new src\League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\PDO\Db('mysql://user:pass@localhost/oauth');

// Initiate the auth server with the models
$server = new src\League\OAuth2\Server\Resource(new League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\PDO\Session($db));
?>
```

Comment: Are you using composer to install dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing namespacing with path declaration. By the way the namespace for `Request` is `League\OAuth2\Server\Util` so the call must be:

```
$request = new League\OAuth2\Server\Util\Request();
```

But before using it you need an autoloader or you must include the class.

```
include __DIR__."/src/League/OAuth2/Server/Util/Request.php";
```

If you need an autoloader you can use the PSR-0 autoloader:

[SplClassLoader.php](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634)

Else read about PHP namespaces: [Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)